# How to index Spark CoreNLP analysis?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, stanford-nlp

I have been using the [Stanford CoreNLP wrapper for Apache Spark](https://github.com/databricks/spark-corenlp) to do NEP analysis and found it works well. However, i want to extend the simple example to where I can map the analysis back to an original dataframe id. See below, I have added two more row to the simple example.

```
val input = Seq(
  (1, "<xml>Apple is located in California. It is a great company.</xml>"),
  (2, "<xml>Google is located in California. It is a great company.</xml>"),
  (3, "<xml>Netflix is located in California. It is a great company.</xml>")
).toDF("id", "text")

input.show()

input: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, text: string]
+---+--------------------+
| id|                text|
+---+--------------------+
|  1|<xml>Apple is loc...|
|  2|<xml>Google is lo...|
|  3|<xml>Netflix is l...|
+---+--------------------+
```

I can then run this dataframe through the Spark CoreNLP wrapper to do both sentiment and NEP analysis.

```
val output = input
  .select(cleanxml('text).as('doc))
  .select(explode(ssplit('doc)).as('sen))
  .select('sen, tokenize('sen).as('words), ner('sen).as('nerTags), sentiment('sen).as('sentiment))
```

However, in the output below i have lost the connection back to the original dataframe row ids.

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+
|                 sen|               words|             nerTags|sentiment|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+
|Apple is located ...|[Apple, is, locat...|[ORGANIZATION, O,...|        2|
|It is a great com...|[It, is, a, great...|  [O, O, O, O, O, O]|        4|
|Google is located...|[Google, is, loca...|[ORGANIZATION, O,...|        3|
|It is a great com...|[It, is, a, great...|  [O, O, O, O, O, O]|        4|
|Netflix is locate...|[Netflix, is, loc...|[ORGANIZATION, O,...|        3|
|It is a great com...|[It, is, a, great...|  [O, O, O, O, O, O]|        4|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+
```

Ideally, I want something like the following:

```
+--+---------------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+
|id|                  sen|               words|             nerTags|sentiment|
+--+---------------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+
| 1| Apple is located ...|[Apple, is, locat...|[ORGANIZATION, O,...|        2|
| 1| It is a great com...|[It, is, a, great...|  [O, O, O, O, O, O]|        4|
| 2| Google is located...|[Google, is, loca...|[ORGANIZATION, O,...|        3|
| 2| It is a great com...|[It, is, a, great...|  [O, O, O, O, O, O]|        4|
| 3| Netflix is locate...|[Netflix, is, loc...|[ORGANIZATION, O,...|        3|
| 3| It is a great com...|[It, is, a, great...|  [O, O, O, O, O, O]|        4|
+--+---------------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+
```

I have tried to create a UDF but am unable to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using UDF defined in the [Stanford CoreNLP wrapper for Apache Spark](https://github.com/databricks/spark-corenlp,) you can use the following code to produced the desired output

```
val output = input.withColumn("doc", cleanxml('text).as('doc))
  .withColumn("sen", ssplit('doc).as('sen))
  .withColumn("sen", explode($"sen"))
  .withColumn("words", tokenize('sen).as('words))
  .withColumn("ner", ner('sen).as('nerTags))
  .withColumn("sentiment", sentiment('sen).as('sentiment))
  .drop("text")
  .drop("doc").show()
```

will produce the following Dataframe

```
+--+---------------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+
|id|                  sen|               words|             nerTags|sentiment|
+--+---------------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+
| 1| Apple is located ...|[Apple, is, locat...|[ORGANIZATION, O,...|        2|
| 1| It is a great com...|[It, is, a, great...|  [O, O, O, O, O, O]|        4|
| 2| Google is located...|[Google, is, loca...|[ORGANIZATION, O,...|        3|
| 2| It is a great com...|[It, is, a, great...|  [O, O, O, O, O, O]|        4|
| 3| Netflix is locate...|[Netflix, is, loc...|[ORGANIZATION, O,...|        3|
| 3| It is a great com...|[It, is, a, great...|  [O, O, O, O, O, O]|        4|
+--+---------------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+
```